# Sensitivity and Specificity of model

Tags: machine-learning, confusion-matrix

If I have an image dataset with two classes : Normal and abnormal , In addition to accuracy metric, I would like to add sensitivity and specificity criterions.
So, How can I introduce those two metrics to calculate the performance of my model.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may print a classification report from

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report

and you will have access to the metrics ('accuracy', 'f1', 'recall', 'precision') simply by printing

print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))

In case you are not using python, as you know accuracy is calculated as TP + TN / (TP + TN + FP + FN) where TP = true positive, TN = true negative, FP = false positive, FN = false negative.

Similarly,

recall = sensitivity = TP / (TP + FN) -- defined for each class in a multiclass problem

specificity = TN / (TN + FP) --defined for each class in a multiclass problem (I don't think sklearn returns specificity directly (in python), so you may have to define a function for that)

You may get the values TN, TP, FP, FN from your confusion matrix

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate `sensitivity` and `specificity` using directly a confusion matrix (as mentioned by @GaussianPrior) or you may just use the sklearn's method `recall_score`.
Calculating sensitivity, or just recall:

```
sensitivity = sklearn.recall_score(true , pred)
```

Specificity, which is just a "sensitivity for the negative class", can be extracted using the same recall_score just inverting both true and pred boolean values:

```
specificity = sklearn.recall_score(np.logical_not(true) , np.logical_not(pred))
```